# Failed review task

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I probably should (and will) give up on reviewing. I failed an review audit after doing some successful review audits and had been banned for two days. (I might be mistake but I think it was the only one). My first question is why is the threshold ban for review after one (or two) failures? I don't have the feeling that I've learned something out of this single(?) failure. I just had a 30 days ban which was kind of justified, but also "too early".

The task I failed on feels like a mess and I'm not sure why I'm actually failed.
The task was:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/11357896

I actually had a bad feeling about that review, but not due to the answer, more because the question looks like a mess. After reading it multiple times I'm not really sure that I understand what the author was asking. However, more importantly for someone who is not an expert in that area (which is the second reason I should have pressed skip), I still think this looks like a valid answer. Based on the comments in the full post it sounds very logical that the image is clipped due to some priority issue.

However, what really annoys me currently, is the comment below the answer which wasn't visible during reviewing. I really can not understand why this should be a comment. It might be a bad answer but it is not a comment.

Hope to get some insight in my mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood it -- subtle.difference. Based on the comments in the "real question" I understood it correctly: Part of the line is occluded by the video. This might be due to the order in which things are painted, which might be a priority issue. Hence, the answer looks valid to me. The only thing I would be unsure is,whether it solves the problem, as I didn't fully reproduce it....

Comment: If you do go back to reviewing, remember that if you aren't sure, skip.

Comment: In addiiton I would say: avoid first posts like .... whatever. Nevertheless, I'm still wondering why the answer is a bad answer. Furthermore I'm pretty confident that the answer in doubt wouldn't make a good comment.
However, most likely I will remove the review button via a browser script ;)

Comment: Oh boy. You thought "No action needed" was the right call? Please do give up on reviewing. The audit was working correctly this time. Not sure why you're focused on the comment appearing or not appearing; you don't need the comment to see that post is in desperate need of attention.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm not sure what your comment is supposed to add to the question. There is one fairly good answer and an extremely good answer in the referenced duplicate question. There was a misunderstanding on the goal on my side..... that's all

Comment: None of those answers make the point that this is *not* a borderline case, there should be *nothing* confusing about this review. Lots of people come to Meta and complain about borderline cases. The answers here and other places talk about rules and expected behaviors in particular queues. That is not what went wrong here. It was not a misunderstanding of the goal, it was a misunderstanding of the fact that that is a crappy answer and is *never* something that you should be "okay" with.

Comment: @CodeGray: And there you are mistaken: "misunderstanding of the goal". Yes it was. I'm pretty sure as it was me who had a misunderstanding. And the result of this question will be me acting differently in future. If I will review first-posts again. Secondly, the first paragraph of the answer by Servy addresses exactly this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this was in the LQP queue then doing nothing would be fine.  The post is *an answer*, and shouldn't be *deleted*, but it also needs a *lot* of help, and it's *absolutely* wrong to do nothing.

It has content that's not actually a quote in a quote.  It has an image as a link, rather than an embedded image.  Sentences aren't capitalized or punctuated properly.  And of course the post could really use a downvote, based on its quality. And then of course it would be appropriate to comment on all of these problems on the post as well, either instead of or in addition to making some of the changes (the grammar/formatting would probably be better to just fix though).

Saying that there's *nothing* that you could do to help that post from the First Post queue is just wrong.